# ng:areq Argument 'loginController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

My code is as shown below:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>quflip</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="quflipMobWeb">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller/loginController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller/driverController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller/driversController.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('quflipMobWeb', [
    'quflipMobWeb.services',
    'quflipMobWeb.controllers',
    'ngRoute'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when("/drivers", { templateUrl: "template/drivers.html", controller: "driversController" }).
    when("/drivers/:id", { templateUrl: "template/driver.html", controller: "driverController" }).
    when("/login", { templateUrl: "template/login.html", controller: "loginController" }).
    otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
}]);
```

loginController.js

```
angular.module('quflipMobWeb.controllers', [])
    .controller('loginController', function($scope) {
        console.log("tested");
    });
```

login.html

```
<div class="q-login-background">
    <h3>It is website,enjoy it</h3>
</div>
```

app.css

```
/* app css stylesheet */

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

login.css

```
.q-login-background {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    /* background: url ("../img/ic_login.jpg") no-repeat; */
}
```

The moment I run it, it give me error:

`Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'loginController' is not a function, got undefined`. What am I missing here?

Comment: remove `[]` from this line `angular.module('quflipMobWeb.controllers', [])` and try

Comment: It gives me two error `[$injector:nomod] Module 'quflipMobWeb.controllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.` and `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'loginController' is not a function, got undefined`

Comment: see this https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod

Comment: if your probem is solved accept the right answer

Comment: Unfortunately, none of this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the add the ctrl and service script before the `app.js`

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller/loginController.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller/driverController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller/driversController.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, app.js is main component it should be first, I think

Comment: but according to the structure `app` and `loginController` separate modules and `loginController` injected to the `app` module. so `loginController.js` script should come before the `app.js` script

Comment: I tried your way, but error is same `[ng:areq] Argument 'loginController' is not a function, got undefined`

Comment: but you cant put sub component first and then main component. let him try then will see

Answer (score 0):

When you define submodule, you need to define it first and then use it

```
angular.module('quflipMobWeb.controllers', [])
```

and then use it like this

```
angular.module('quflipMobWeb.controllers')
    .controller('loginController', function($scope) {
        console.log("tested");
    });
```

When you going to use it like this

```
angular.module('quflipMobWeb.controllers', [])
    .controller...
```

There is no module defined with name `quflipMobWeb.controllers`, it will throw `nomod` error

check this link out 
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod

Answer (score 0):

the problem should be on the way you call you controller module on 'loginController':

move the module declaration on top of **app.js**:

```
angular.module('quflipMobWeb.controllers', [])
```

and then reference that module on **loginController.js** like this:

```
angular.module('quflipMobWeb.controllers') //no empty array argument since your not declaring the module here!
    .controller('loginController', function($scope) {
        console.log("tested");
    });
```

Remember this:

```
angular.module("noop", []) //declare, usually on app.js

angular.module("noop") //retrieve anywhere you need it
```